# MVC 4 - detail page with two models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create a blog detail page with comments at the bottom of the page. I use my "Post" model which as some properties and a navigation list property of my comments.

What I want to do is to create a form at the very bottom of the page to add a new comment. Since I use an different model for the comment I have trouble to figure out how to create a scenario like this.

Thanks for any suggestions.

**EDIT**
Here is some code for better explanation:

```
@model Skuami.Models.PostModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Title;
}

<div class="blogContentBox">
    <div class="blogImage">
        <img src="@Model.Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="blogContent">
        <div class="blogDate">@Model.CreateDate</div>
        <p class="blogTitle">@Model.Title</p>
        @Model.Content
    </div>
</div>

<p class="commentTitle">
    @Model.Comments.Count @(Model.Comments.Count == 1 ? " comment" : " comments")
</p>

@foreach (var item in Model.Comments)
{
    <div class="commentBox">
        <p class="commentName">@item.Name</p>
        <p class="commentDate">@item.CreateDate</p>
        @item.Message
    </div>
}

<div class="commentBox">
    <p class="commentReply">Leave a Reply</p>

     @using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "CommentModel" }))
    {

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend></legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments.Name) <!-- how can I use a 2nd model -->
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name) <!-- how can I use a 2nd model -->
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message) <!-- how can I use a 2nd model -->
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message) <!-- how can I use a 2nd model -->
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
     }
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a `ViewModel`. Basically, it's a wrapper for everything:

```
public class BlogDetailViewModel {
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public Comment NewComment { get; set; }
}
```

Then, your view takes a model of type `BlogDetailViewModel`. You would use `NewComment` for the new one:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewComment.Email)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewComment.CommentContent)
```

..etc.

In your controller.. you construct it:

```
return View(new BlogDetailViewModel() { Post = thePostVariable, Comments = getCommentsForPost(), NewComment = new Comment() });
```

On post, your `NewComment` member will contain the new comment data.

Comment: His model already has comments, he's trying to figure out how to get the post data out, I think.

Comment: Nice answer.  I was thinking there should be a way to retrieve it from the Comment collection, but this is simpler and more intuitive.

Comment: thanks, this is a good way to solve the problem. I was also trying to retrieve the data through the Comment collection of my post model.

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
  public class CustomerModel
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        public string customerName { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> customerNameList { get; set; }
}



  public class RegisterModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }


        public string Name { get; set; }


        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }


        public string Address { get; set; }

        public CustomerModel _Customer { get; set; }


    }
```

View

```
@model TwoModelInSinglePage.Models.RegisterModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Content", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FrmIndex" }))
        { 
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address)
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNo)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNo)
            </div>
           <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m._Customer.customerName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m._Customer.customerName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m._Customer.customerName)
            </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your comment form a partial view that posts somewhere and returns to the page, or does some AJAX, which is probably the better option here as it gives a better user experience.